# req.body undefined...how can i solve

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

```
[  server.js  ]

const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const data = fs.readFileSync("./database.json");
const conf = JSON.parse(data);

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: conf.host,
    user: conf.user,
    password: conf.password,
    port: conf.port,
    database: conf.database
});

connection.connect();

app.get("/api/users", (req, res) => {
    connection.query(
        "select * from users where isDeleted = 0",
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        }
    );
});


app.post("/api/users", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "insert into users values (null,?,?,now(),now(),0)";
    let name = req.body.name;
    let dsc = req.body.dsc;
    let params = [name, dsc];
    console.log(params);
    connection.query(sql, params,
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        });
});

app.delete("/api/users/:id", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "update users set isDeleted = 1 where id = ?";
    let params =[req.params.id];
    connection.query(sql,params,
        (err, rows, fields)=>{
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Describe the bug

I am trying to send form data to my API but req.body is undefined for some reason.

To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

create a new request
enter your API endpoint URL
select the body tab and then select the form-data tab
enter the key name of the form data you are trying to send so your API can recognize it and then the value.
Click send and you should get a response with a status code of 200. If you get an error like me telling me that req.body is undefined then you have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using `bodyparser.json()`. From the documentation, this will parse requests that are **only** in JSON. You are better off using `bodyParser.urlencoded([options])`.
2. I advise using `express.urlencoded` instead.

Read [this](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for clarification

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the router

```js
[  server.js  ]

const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const data = fs.readFileSync("./database.json");
const conf = JSON.parse(data);

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: conf.host,
    user: conf.user,
    password: conf.password,
    port: conf.port,
    database: conf.database
});

connection.connect();

// u need a router
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/api/users", (req, res) => {
    connection.query(
        "select * from users where isDeleted = 0",
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        }
    );
});


router.post("/api/users", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "insert into users values (null,?,?,now(),now(),0)";
    let name = req.body.name;
    let dsc = req.body.dsc;
    let params = [name, dsc];
    console.log(params);
    connection.query(sql, params,
        (err, rows, fields) => {
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        });
});

router.delete("/api/users/:id", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "update users set isDeleted = 1 where id = ?";
    let params =[req.params.id];
    connection.query(sql,params,
        (err, rows, fields)=>{
            res.send(rows);
            // console.log(err);
            // console.log(rows);
        });
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: ohh!!!!

I see the problem, look if you have postman send the body in `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. 
The problem is not the back, is the front

you have to stringify the body

```js

const data = { username: 'example' };

fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: look at the updolading dara example